# Issues with capturing Array value to php variable

Tags: php

I have a Cookie string from a dynamic table that is looped and arrayed on the 7th index. I then check which array is empty and produce my outputs.
For the line that says `$role = $array[0];` where I have the print `$role`. It will print what I need put it will output about 5 times.

My Attempt:
If I try to place the `print $role` outside the for loop it will print once and not print when other instances $role value was passed.

```
if (!empty($_COOKIE['arr'])) {
    $arr = $_COOKIE['arr'];
    $array = explode (",", $arr);

    $role='';

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array ); $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 7; $j < count($array ); $j++) {
            if (!empty($array[$j]) ){
                print_r($array[$i]);
                echo '<br>';
            }
            break;
        } 
        if (empty($array[$j]) ){
            print_r($array[$i]);
            echo '<br>'; 
            for ($m = 0; $m < strlen($array[$i]); $m++) {
                $role = $array[0]; 
                print $role; 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //print $role;
}
```

Comment: What does that have to do with Java ?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Why do you have `break;` in both inner loops which is always executed?

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here.

Comment: @NigelRen thats exactly what I was willing to ask. You mentioned your first loop would be iteracting seven times. It is actualy iteracting once because of that `break;`

Comment: Maybe if you showed us what was in `$_COOKIE['arr']` some of this would make more sense